# Why DOMDocument::validate() request faild?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I made a function, which help me validate my html document. It works, but when it achive `$doc->validate()` part i have a error оа Maximum execution time

```
/* This my function and arrays */
$correct_html_array = ['<a>', '<div>', '</div>', '</a>', '<span>', '</span>'];
$incorrect_html_array = ['<a>', '<div>', '</a>', '<p>' , '</tr>'];

function validate_html($html_array) {

    $tags = htmlspecialchars(implode("", $html_array));

    $html_doc="<!DOCTYPE html>" . "<html><body>" . $tags . "</body></html>"; 

    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    $doc->loadHTML($html_doc);

    if($doc->validate()) { // here is a Maximum execution time error
        echo 'Код валидный!';
    } else {  
        echo 'Код не валидный!';
    }

}


validate_html($incorrect_html_array);
```

/** Here is an error */

> Warning:
>   DOMDocument::validate(http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\task_4.php on line 22
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): I/O warning : failed to load
>   external entity "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd" in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\task_4.php on line 22
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Could not load the external subset
>   "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd" in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\task_4.php on line 22
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\task_4.php on line 22Warning:
>   DOMDocument::validate(http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\task_4.php on line 22
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): I/O warning : failed to load
>   external entity "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd" in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\task_4.php on line 22
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Could not load the external subset
>   "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd" in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\task_4.php on line 22
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\task_4.php on line 22

I will appriciate if you help me to solve this problem

Comment: Are you running the above code using `https` ?

Comment: I use localhost XAMPP

Comment: ??? but does your localhost server use https or not? It's just a thought that the urls mentioned in the error are all http but the actual live DTD is https

Comment: how to activate it? and what is DTD?

Comment: I have no idea if XAMPP offers SSL or not so I cannot advise how "to activate it". `DTD` stands for `Document Type Definition` which is basically `"The specification"` of the document in question ( in this case HTML ) - the error message is quite clear but the reason for it not loading is not - hence wondering if this is an issue regarding the protocol used.

Comment: I tested a simple scenario and it also timed out ( php 7.2.9 ) - initial thoughts about protocol were proven wrong with these tests. It would be interesting to know if the same happens in earlier versions of this function/method